# Need some help debugging this PHP

Tags: mysql, database, php

I coded this up a bit ago, but it's not working.

I realize I could do this simpler, but I'm trying to use OOP.

So here is the code..

**database.class.php**

```
<?php

class config {

    public $host;
    public $user;
    public $pass;

    function __construct($host=NULL,$user=NULL,$pass=NULL) {

        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;

    }

    function __destruct() {}

}

class database {

    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $config;

    function __construct($config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    function __destruct() {}

    public function openCon() {
        mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);
        if (mysql_errno()) {
            printf('Failed to connect: %s', mysql_error());
        } else {
            echo 'Connected to DB successfully.<br/><br/>';
        }
    }

    public function closeCon() {
        try {
            mysql_close();
            echo 'Successfully closed connection.<br/><br/>';
        } catch (exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include('db.class.php');

    $con = new config('localhost','root','');
    $etc = new database($con);
    $etc->openCon();
    mysql_select_db('tester') or die(mysql_error());
    $query1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM person') or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query1) or die(mysql_error());
        echo 'First: ' . $rows['First'];
        echo 'Age:'    . $rows['Age'];
    $etc->closeCon();
?>
```

I'm sure there are blaring errors in this. Could anyone help me find and fix them?

It says: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'tester'

Not sure why.

I specified root as the user, but it came back with '' as the user I requested to use.

It got the host and the database right.

There is no password to my local root user, so...

Any ideas?

Comment: The `Access denied` error means that you have not provided the correct login information. Fix that first.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen That's the thing. It's correct. I've logged in with those details before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem is that the host, user and password are never set. Look in the `database` constructor. You only set the configuration.

Either set the private `database` properties somehow, or use the configuration object in `openCon()`.

Or, even better, just scrap the `config` object. Right now it plays no significant role. Just change the `database` constructor like the following and be done with it:

```
function __construct($host, $user, $pass) {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
}
```

Finally, if the `__destruct()` method does not do anything then you do not need to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Your every thing is correct just you need to change in your database class. You pass $config as an object to the constructor of the database class so to access the variable from that object you need little change. It should be

```
 class database {

private $host;
private $user;
private $pass;
private $config;
public $Connectionlink;

function __construct($config) {
    $this->host = $config->host;
    $this->user = $config->user;
    $this->pass = $config->pass;
}

 // function __destruct() {} as your destruct function doing noting so you need not to include this.

public function openCon() {
   $this->Connectionlink= mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);
    if (mysql_errno()) {
        printf('Failed to connect: %s', mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo 'Connected to DB successfully.<br/><br/>';
    }
}

public function closeCon() {
    try {
        mysql_close();
        echo 'Successfully closed connection.<br/><br/>';
    } catch (exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
}
```

mysql_select_db need two parameters, so it should be

```
  mysql_select_db('tester', $etc->Connectionlink) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

just try to navigate to your mysql directory using cmd
in xampp its "C:\xampp\mysql\bin"

and then type 
"mysql -u root" and check whether you are getting access